# Definition of distribution function for a Lebesgue-Stiljes measure

Tags: real-analysis

In Folland's Real Analysis, he defines the distribution function of a finite Borel measure $\mu$ as $F(x) = \mu(-\infty, x]$, then proves that it's increasing and right-continuous, etc. But this definition seems to only work when $\mu(\Bbb{R}) < \infty$. If $\mu$ is a Borel measure that is finite on all bounded Borel sets, but may be infinite on unbounded Borel sets, how does one define the corresponding function?

EDIT: I believe I asked my question incorrectly. As per a comment I just made, what I was looking for was not exactly what I asked for. In this case, a couple pages later, Folland defines the function required as: $$ 
F(x) = \left \lbrace \begin{array}{cc}
\mu(0,x] & \text{if } x>0 \\ 
0 & \text{if } x=0 \\ 
-\mu(x,0] & \text{if } x<0 \\ 
\end{array} \right.. $$ Then $F$ is the corresponding function.

Comment: You don't.$\,\,\,$

Comment: @zhw. This is somewhat unsatisfying. I was given the task of showing there is a one-to-one correspondence between increasing, right continuous functions and Borel measures that are finite on all bounded Borel sets. If there is no way to define the distribution function in the case that the measure is infinite, then the task is untenable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition works whenever intervals of the form $]-\infty, x]$ have finite measure, so it includes cases where $\mu(\mathbb R)=\infty$.  If such intervals have infinite measure a distribution function doesn't seem to make much sense.

p.s. I have just read your comment. You would not need a distribution function but e.g. the function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $x\mapsto \mu(]x,0])$ if $x<0$ and $\mu([0,x])$ if $x\geq 0$.  Distribution functions wouldn't yield he bijection anyway, as they do not cover all increasing, right continuous functions.